# Initialize Array of hashes using a struct

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I am receiving an array of parameters [config['events']] that looks like this:

```
 [{"event"=>"loaded", "tags"=>["videjbajc_jbad"]}, {"event"=>"clicked"}, 
 {"event"=>"downloaded"}, {"url"=>"http://aintnothingbutarailsthing"}....}]
```

I am trying to run validations on each hash key, this should be dynamic since the input might change, hash key name stay the same.

First step - call events method to map each array of hashes:

```
   def valid?
        @errors = []
        @errors << 'Please check events unless self.events.all?(&:valid?)
        @errors.empty?
   end
```

second step - run map to my Events class

```
   def events
         @events ||= (config['events'] || []).map { |e| Event.create(e) }
   end
```

Final step - receive data array object and proceed to initialize and validate

```
  class Event < Struct.new(
                        :event,
                        :link_type,
                        :url,
                        :media_id,
                        ....  
                      )

   def self.create(data)
      self.new(     
            data['event'],
            data['link_type'],
            data['url'],
            data['media_id'],
            ...
          )
     end

      validates :event, :presence => true
      validates :url, :allow_nil => true, :format => /https:/
      .. and so on and so forth.. :-)
 end
```

Problem: Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I can only initialize the event key. Putting in a raise after self.create(data) #{data.inspect} will return

```
       {"event"=>"loaded", "tags"=>["amex_video_q3_delivered"]}
```

:event will validate okay, but tags will not and everything else too.. :-(

Please advise :-)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to correctly initialize my array of hashes using the struct mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. When passing my array of parameters i had to account for every possible key value pair condition.

I initialized it like this:

```
            data['event'],
            data['tags'] ? data['tags'] : nil,
            data['link_type'],
            data['url'],
            data['media_id'],
            data['ad_placement'] ? data['ad_placement'] : nil,
            data['points'] ? data['points'].to_i : nil,
            data['award'] ? data['award'] : nil,               
            data['points_tag'] ? data ['points_tag'] : nil,
            data['track'] ? data['track'] : nil,
            data['checkin_completed_ttl'] ? data['checkin_completed_ttl'] : nil
```

making sure to expect a nil value for certain keys.